# How to reply to comments received for any question

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I have posted a question and have received a comment to the question. I want to reply to the comment and also inform the commenter of the reply. How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 3):

You can either reply with another comment like:

> @Username: Your comment goes here.

or just add detail to your original question or answer if you are the OP and it is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You'd just add another comment in order to reply, but to specifically let someone know you'd have to leave a comment on one of the posts they own (a question or answer that they posted).  They won't get notified if your comment reply is attached to your question.